# Cannot start wildfly with systemd

Tags: centos7, wildfly

Centos 7

Wildfly-16.0.0.Beta1

JDK 1.8.0_212

I cannot start wildfly with "systemctl start wildfly" but I can start it with "/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh standalone standalone.xml 192.168.56.200 &"

```
Config file:
# cat /etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
# The configuration you want to run
WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone.xml

# The mode you want to run
WILDFLY_MODE=standalone

# The address to bind to
WILDFLY_BIND=192.168.56.200
```

Systemctl status

```
[root@liferay ~]# systemctl status wildfly -l
● wildfly.service - The WildFly Application Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-22 17:42:47 +08; 14min ago
  Process: 12925 ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12925 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 22 17:42:46 liferay systemd[1]: Started The WildFly Application Server.
Apr 22 17:42:47 liferay systemd[1]: wildfly.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 22 17:42:47 liferay systemd[1]: Unit wildfly.service entered failed state.
Apr 22 17:42:47 liferay systemd[1]: wildfly.service failed.
```

systemd unit

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
User=wildfly
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/var/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG  $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I make this work with systemd?

Comment: Check in debug.log where WILDFLY_HOME is. You probably have to add it to /etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf .

Comment: @Overmind I could not find it in /opt/wildfly or /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/. Do I need to configure something to enable it?

Comment: @Overmind The `launch.sh` script sets it to `/opt/wildfly` if the user hasn't provided one.

Comment: WILDFLY_HOME is not defined in wildfly.conf . It should be there.

Comment: @Overmind I have added "WILDFLY_HOME=/opt/wildfly" in /etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf but it still failed to start

Comment: Is it the same error ?

Comment: @Overmind yes, same error

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking supplied systemd unit, I found that there's a PID folder set

```
mkdir /var/run/wildfly/
chown wildfly. /var/run/wildfly/
```

these commands fixed it.